# How to get rating values when click on the stars in php?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to give the user to rate stars and also I want to update the database value after the user is rating it.

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php foreach($genres as $genre){
    $jsqla = mysql_query("select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where genre='$genre' limit 0,5");

    while($jrowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla)){
        if($jrowa['rate_number'] > 0){ $ratea = $jrowa['rate_score'] / $jrowa['rate_number']; }else{ $ratea = 0; 
    }
?>
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;"/>
```

Comment: you didn't close the while I think

Comment: And what's the issue? What's working so far? What's not? This is a little ambiguous in its current form...

Comment: Vaisakh Pc is right same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple rating using html/javascript

```
//HTML:
    <form class="rating" method="post">
                <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="postToController();" /><label for="star5" title="Super !!">5 stars</label>    
                <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="postToController();" /><label for="star4" title="Geil">4 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" onclick="postToController();" /><label for="star3" title="Gut">3 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" onclick="postToController();" /><label for="star2" title="So gut wie">2 stars</label>
                <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" onclick="postToController();" /><label for="star1" title="Schlecht">1 star</label>
    </form> 

//Javascript:
function postToController() {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('rating').length; i++) {
                if(document.getElementsByName('rating')[i].checked == true) {
                    var ratingValue = document.getElementsByName('rating')[i].value;
                    break;
                }
        }
        alert(ratingValue);
}
```

Here is good solution for rating system in php [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php--net-11541)